# OCR on Selected Area

Tags: c#, winforms

How can I only get [selection area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWCw1.jpg) to converted OCR?
Currently, the process is a static image to be opened then convert the full page.

```cs
private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    selection.mouseDown(e);
    pictureBox1.Refresh();
}


private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        var img = new Bitmap(openFileDialog.FileName);
        var ocr = new TesseractEngine("./tessdata", "eng", EngineMode.TesseractAndCube);
        var page = ocr.Process(img);
        txtResult.Text = page.GetText();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a variabel to save MouseDown position. Maybe your `selection` variable does this already. And use the picturebox MouseUp event to get the area. Then grab the area to a bitmap.

```
private Point _MouseDownCoordinates;

private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    //selection.mouseDown(e);
    _MouseDownCoordinates = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
    pictureBox1.Refresh();
}

private void pictureBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Int32 deltaX = e.X - _MouseDownCoordinates.X;
    Int32 deltaY = e.Y - _MouseDownCoordinates.Y;
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(_MouseDownCoordinates, new Size(deltaX, deltaY));

    var img = new Bitmap(deltaX, deltaY, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
    using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(img))
    {
        g.CopyFromScreen(panel1.PointToScreen(_MouseDownCoordinates), new Point(0, 0), rect.Size);

        var ocr = new TesseractEngine("./tessdata", "eng", EngineMode.TesseractAndCube);
        var page = ocr.Process(img);
        txtResult.Text = page.GetText();
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks sir ,let me try

Comment: DllNotFoundException: Failed to find library "liblept172.dll" for platform x64.

Comment: One question, one problem on stackoverflow... I expected you need to know how the grab a bitmap from selected region. If your question is how to initialize and use Tesseract, please create a new question and follow the instructions on [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: ok sir sorry , but the idea works ill create new question now sir thank you